# Get all text from particular element(s)

Tags: jquery

If I have the following

```
var url = this.data;
$.get(url, {}, function(data){
    alert(data);


});
```

I'm successfully able to iterate through and alert the following:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="arboretum-smith" class="bullet" rel="251-195">&nbsp;</a> 
    <div class="popup" id="arboretum-smith-box"> 
        <h3>Title 1</h3> 
        <div class="popupcontent"> 
            <p>Description text to go here.</p> 
        </div>
        <a class="close" href="javascript:void(0)">Close</a> 
    </div> 

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="old-well" class="bullet" rel="251-245">&nbsp;</a> 
    <div class="popup" id="old-well-box"> 
        <h3>Title 2</h3> 
        <div class="popupcontent"> 
            <p>Description text to go here.</p> 
        </div>
        <a class="close" href="javascript:void(0)">Close</a> 
    </div> 

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="bell-tower" class="bullet" rel="100-100">&nbsp;</a> 
    <div class="popup" id="bell-tower-box"> 
        <h3>Title 3</h3> 
        <div class="popupcontent"> 
            <p>Description text to go here.</p> 
        </div>
        <a class="close" href="javascript:void(0)">Close</a> 
    </div>
```

However what I want to do is get the text between the `<h3></h3>'s` Eg. Title 1, Title 2 etc. What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the string `"Title 1Title 2Title 3"`,

```
$(data).find('h3').text()
```

if you want the array(-like object) `["Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3"]`,

```
$(data).find('h3').map(function(){return $(this).text();})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alert($(data).filter('#arboretum-smith-box h3').text());
```